# Migrate android billing 4 to 5 - , queryPurchases, getPurchasesList, getSku

Tags: java, android

When i migrate android billing version 4 to 5 . I get a error about QueryPurchases.

My code error

```
public boolean isSubscriptionRunning() {
    return billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS).getPurchasesList() != null
            && !billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS).getPurchasesList().isEmpty();
}
```

Error: Cannot resolve method 'queryPurchases' in 'BillingClient'.
Please help me migrate this.